# Syntax errors in hard to reach JS environments

Tags: javascript, debugging, syntax-error, opera, opera-extension

I'm making an Opera Extension. It includes a background script which fails very silently. It runs in a unique environment, so I can't take it just anywhere to check if it works (it needs predefined variables). Is there a way to debug scripts without running them. That is, checking if the syntax is correct. I want something like JSLint, that instead of telling me how my code is bad tells me where the syntax errors are.

Comment: +1 for "JSLint telling me how my code is bad".

Comment: I've not made an Opera extension, but I have worked with UserScript stuff in Chrome, Firefox and IE.  JSHint/JSLint are a great choice, and when that fails I turn my extension/userscript into a regular JS file that I include in the page I'm working on.  That way I get regular browser-level debugging tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want a quick search for *SyntaxErrors*, you could drop the code into Closure Compiler, and just choose the *"Whitespace Only"* option.

It'll notify you of invalid code without any code styling analysis to clutter things up.

http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home

If you choose the *"Pretty Print"* option, it'll also give you a well indented result in case the original code needed some cleanup.